# Link to external URL using richfaces

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am currently displaying a ticket number like so.

```
<h:outputText value="#{ticket.ticketNumber}" />
```

Instead of this I want a hyper-link to a URL.

The address will look similar to this: http://testserver.com/viewer.jsp?ticket=#{ticket.ticketNumber}

So, the new code might look something like this (note the code below doesn't work, just a concept).

```
<a4j:commandLink action="http://testserver.com/viewer.jsp?ticket=#{ticket.ticketNumber}"
                 value="#{ticket.ticketNumber}" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`command*` controls are generally `UICommand` instances - for invoking server-side logic. Use an [outputLink](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/h/outputLink.html):

```
<h:outputLink
    value="http://testserver.com/viewer.jsp?ticket=#{ticket.ticketNumber}">
  <h:outputText value="#{ticket.ticketNumber}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

Comment: my requirement is same but i also need rerender functionality . any suggestions ???

Comment: @RahulRazdan Your requirement sounds completely different. You would be better off asking a new question with detailed requirements and sample code of what you have tried.

Comment: i have a h:dataTable component , for each row i have delete link action , when i click on delete it is deleting that particular row but i want it to reRender that dataTable after deletion

Comment: @RahulRazdan You can ask questions on the [Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page.